# How can I show a banner UIView as part of the UINavigationController, when in some VC's vs others

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say we have a CustomNavigationController that subclass UINavigationController.

Let's use the following example to explain the question.

CustomNavC -> pushes on VC A. From VC A you can push on 2 different VC's. VC B and VC C. We'll say both these VC's push on various other VC's, further down the rabbit hole.

Now, let's say we want to show a UIView that acts as a banner view appearing directly underneath the navigation controller. However, we only want the banner to show on say VC A, VC C, VC E, VC J, etc.

Is there any possible way to do this from the CustomNavC itself? Or is the only way to gain this control of which VC's show the banner... is to put it on the VC's itself?

1) We put it on the CustomNavC view. When the user moves from a VC to a VC that both show the banner (A->C), we want to same banner to remain. We gain this by laying out the banner on the CustomNavC. However, how can we check whether a VC should be displaying the banner or not? Every time the NavC pushes or pops a VC, we would have to check. Likely some function on each VC like `-(BOOL)allowBannerViewDisplay` and VC's can opt in.

2) If we put the BannerView on individual VC's, it becomes a bit easier but the deal breaker is that if we move from VC A -> VC C, the user is going to see 2 separate banners during the transition instead of the same banner.

So, we need to solve it way 1. The CustomNavC listens for a notification and displays the banner. It would then need to check the currently displaying VC and only display the banner if the VC allowed it. However, if the user transitions to another VC, it needs to recheck the logic of whether the banner is currently displaying and if it is, check if that VC wants it to display.

All of this feels weird to me.

Suggestions?

Comment: Opinion: The pattern where the nav controller decides seems reasonable to me.  It's conceptually similar to every `UIViewController` having a `shouldAutorotate` property.

Answer (score 0):

I've never implemented something like this, but off the bat my thought is this:

Set up this custom view as a new class, and pass the reference along your VCs. Set up a method on the custom View as a class method that takes in a UIViewController and returns a bool for whether or not it should be displayed (rather than on each of your VCs). This class method can get the class and see if it exists in an array of class names or something.

Now, I've never moved a UIView from one VC to another, but I think it's possible to remove the UIView as a subview from the VC it's on, and place it on the new one as a subview.

Alternatively, perhaps you could have a datasource/delegate object for this custom view, and create a new custom UIView on each VC as needed that all reference the same datasource / delegate to set up the state appropriately.